# Securing WebService using @RoleAllowed annotation

Tags: web-services, security, weblogic

I have a plain webservice deployed on a weblogic server which is working as expected. 
Now I want to secure it and I tried using @RolesAllowed but it's not restricting access to the webservice - all users are granted access.

```
@WebService(portName = "WebInternalSoapHTTPPort", serviceName = "InternalService", targetNamespace = "http://test.com/WebInternalServices", endpointInterface = "com.test.webinternal.WebInternal")
@BindingType("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http")
@Policies({@Policy(uri="policy:customPolicy.xml")})

@RolesAllowed (  {
    @SecurityRole (role="developer",
                   mapToPrincipals={ "shilpa"})
} )


public class WebInternalImpl implements WebInternal {


}
```

But when I try to manually add this restriction via Admin Console it works fine.

[image]

Looks like I am missing some configuration to apply security role defined in the JWS file.
Any thoughts are much appreciated.